# React align flex to bottom of a row

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

**Background**

I have this code with 3 blocks in a row. The height of the row is 100px because of the 2nd block.
I want the third (steelblue) block's bottom to be aligned with the middle larger block's bottom.
Right now, I can only get the block tops to align.

**Question**

How can I get a view to align to the bottom of a row that is taller than it is?

**Code so far**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const JustifyContentBasics = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
      }}>
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
      </View>
    );
};

export default JustifyContentBasics;
```

https://snack.expo.io/oQXyEEikE

**What I have tried**

I have tried to wrap the steelblue block with a div, but to no avail.

```
        <div style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
          <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/justify-content)**

[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const JustifyContentBasics = () => {
  return (
    // Try setting `justifyContent` to `center`.
    // Try setting `flexDirection` to `row`.
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
      }}>
      <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }} />
      <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'skyblue' }} />
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            backgroundColor: 'steelblue',
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default JustifyContentBasics;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   import React from 'react';
    import { View } from 'react-native';
    
    const JustifyContentBasics = () => {
        return (
          // Try setting `justifyContent` to `center`.
          // Try setting `flexDirection` to `row`.
          <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between'
          }}>
          <div style={{display:'flex',width: '210px', height: '50px', justifyContent:'space-between'}} >
            <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
            <View style={{width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
          </div>
          <div style={{display:'flex',width: '50px',height:'100px',justifyContent:'flex-end',alignItems:'flex-end'}}>
            <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
          </div>  
            
          </View>
        );
    };

export default JustifyContentBasics;
```

Comment: You are right I did not check the live demo. You already have clear answer but that's another solution with two div  I edited my post

Comment: You are using ```div``` in react-native! It will work with a web browser but not on mobile device.

Comment: I saw in question that owner of question was trying to do modification with div so I did not pay attention about that but thanks!